# Get item from sample list

Tags: java, android

I have this string list:

```
    [InstagramUserSummary(       
            super = Summary@a4acf205,
            is_verified = false, 
            profile_pic_id = 1773528799482591987_1654599017,
            is_favorite = false,
            is_private = false, 
            username = ququletta, 
            pk = 1654599017, 
            profile_pic_url = https://instagram.fada1-5.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/8d99014623ed527e52512a20002d884b/5C387E45/t51.2885-19/s150x150/31203725_200759604054857_5778864946146181120_n.jpg, 
            has_anonymous_profile_picture = false,
            full_name = Ququletta
            )]
```

I just want to get username=

This is possible?

Comment: from where you are getting this list? or how you are adding these values to the list ?

Comment: This is just string I make it. I'll try something for my example project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I guess you are using JAVA.
This code will get the "ququletta" value

```
    String stringValue = "[InstagramUserSummary(super=dev.niekirk.com.instagram4android.requests.payload.InstagramUserSummary@a4acf205, is_verified=false, profile_pic_id=1773528799482591987_1654599017, is_favorite=false, is_private=false, username = ququletta, pk=1654599017, profile_pic_url=https://instagram.fada1-5.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/8d99014623ed527e52512a20002d884b/5C387E45/t51.2885-19/s150x150/31203725_200759604054857_5778864946146181120_n.jpg, has_anonymous_profile_picture=false, full_name=Ququletta)]";

    // First remove all white spaces
    stringValue = stringValue.replaceAll(" ", "");

    // Find where the username key begins
    int beginIndex = stringValue.indexOf("username");

    // Find where the username value ends
    int endIndex = stringValue.indexOf(",", beginIndex);

    // Subtract the username key and value
    String usernameValue = stringValue.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);

    // Get the username value
    System.out.println(usernameValue.split("=")[1]);
```

Comment: Can I ask you something lauer? If I have too time with this list?

Comment: I did not understand your question

Comment: For example, Look my example and think have 2 time multiple with this string and I'll get 2 item between username=

Comment: No, you will get the first match. But your string should not have username duplicated. In case you have, you will have to put in a loop the code.

Comment: If duplicated no way to get both of them?